# DB2 Express in MAC SQL0805N issue

Tags: macos, db2

I have db2 express on mac, db2start works, and db2 connect works.
However when I do anything on the database it gives me an error (eg. db2 list tables):

SQL0805N  Package "NULLID.SQLC2J23 0X4141414141564962" was not found.
SQLSTATE=51002

I try doing this:

```
/Users/myuser/sqllib/bnd> db2 bind @db2ubind.lst blocking all grant public
```

And get these errors:

```
LINE    MESSAGES FOR db2ubind.lst
------  --------------------------------------------------------------------
    SQL0061W  The binder is in progress.

LINE    MESSAGES FOR db2ajgrt.bnd
------  --------------------------------------------------------------------
    SQL0551N  "TESTDB" does not have the required authorization or 
              privilege to perform operation "BIND" on object 
              "NULLID.SQLABJ02".  SQLSTATE=42501

LINE    MESSAGES FOR db2ueiwi.bnd
------  --------------------------------------------------------------------
    SQL0551N  "TESTDB" does not have the required authorization or 
              privilege to perform operation "BIND" on object 
              "NULLID.SQLUAJ19".  SQLSTATE=42501
```

I also already did this (which seems to not help):

```
sudo chown root /Users/$(whoami)/sqllib/security/db2ckpw
sudo chmod u+rxs /Users/$(whoami)/sqllib/security/db2ckpw
sudo chmod o+rx  /Users/$(whoami)/sqllib/security/db2ckpw
```

Did I miss something?

```
#client

> db2level
DB21085I  Instance "blahblah" uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10010" 
with level identifier "0201010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.1.0.0", "s120905", "DARWIN64101", and Fix 
Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/Users/username/sqllib".

#server

 Instance server        = DB2/AIX64 10.5.5
```

Is it not possible to connect from a 10.1 client to 10.5.x server?

Answer (score 0):

The meesage says that you do not have the BIND right in the database.
So ask your DBA to grant you the bind right and redo the bind command.
The DBA has to issue

```
grant bindadd on database to user testdb
grant bind on database to user testdb
```

Alternatively the right could be granted to a group or role or the DBA has to run the bind under his authority.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has no effect.

Comment: re-running the bind shows the same authorization error as before after the rights have been granted to you?